mailx doesn't decode Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
I'm sending mail from python and am trying to read them on the console with mailx. As long as the body of the mail only contains ascii characters the mail is send with charset="ascii" and is readable in mailx.
But if the body of the mail contains non-ascii characters then the mail is send like this:
From root@localhost.qlustar.com  Thu Jul 18 12:59:58 2024
X-Original-To: root
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============2313685126090971503=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: root@localhost.qlustar.com
To: root@localhost.qlustar.com
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2024 12:59:58 +0200
Subject: Action succeeded: Event Restart Resource Groups

--===============2313685126090971503==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

QW4gZXJyb3IgaGFzIG9jY3VyZWQsIHRoZSBmb2xsb3dpbmcgYWN0aW9ucyBoYXZlIGJlZW4gdGFr
ZW4gdG8gY29ycmVjdCBpdDoKCjIKMAoyCjQKIApKCnUKbAogCjEKOAogCjEKMgo6CjUKOQo6CjUK
OAogCuKUlwrilLMK4pSBCiAKWwoxCjMKNQogCnMKdQpjCmMKZQpzCnMKXQogCkUKdgplCm4KdAog
ClIKZQpzCnQKYQpyCnQKIApSCmUKcwpvCnUKcgpjCmUKIApHCnIKbwp1CnAKcwoKCjIKMAoyCjQK
IApKCnUKbAogCjEKOAogCjEKMgo6CjUKOQo6CjUKOAogCiAK4pSXCuKUswrilIEKIApbCjEKMwo3
CiAKcwp1CmMKYwplCnMKcwpdCiAKRQp2CmUKbgp0CiAKUgplCnMKdAphCnIKdAogClIKZQpzCm8K

I can save the mail and then base64 decode the blob to read it but that is rather tedious. I have 'set ttycharset=utf-8' in my .mail.rc and LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and the mail displays properly when manually decoding. So my console is perfectly happy to display the mail.
Isn't there an option for mailx to decode the base64 and display the text directly?
Or do I need to set some option in python so the mail is send differently? I'm using
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
...
smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())

to create and send the mail.
